# create link in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Hi everyone I have a component in joomla 2.5 that show a list of element.
Now I want to view a particular item, how to create a link to past the id of this element and see the whole description
I have this

```
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_productos&view=especialidad8780&Itemid=1'); ?>" >este</>
```

but dont show me the `Itemid=1`

the browser take this router

index.php?option=com_productos&view=especialidad8780&lang=es

this the correct form to do a link in joomla?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

David is right. The "itemId" is a reserved variable for menu item (to set the 'active' class on a clicked menu element). Try to switch to id, productid, ...

And you also have a little mistake in your link (closure a was missing):

```
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_productos&view=especialidad8780&Itemid=1'); ?>" >este</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to link to a particular item, you commonly use `&id=1`. Itemid is reserved for linking to menu items and would be added automatically as necessary by the JRoute call.